# Slow power window issue

Tags: kia, power-windows, forte

On my 2021 Kia forte, the passenger side power window behaves strangely. The window rolls down just fine. However, when closing it, it begins rolling up in the normal rate, but half-way up gets slower until completely stops. I then wait some time and able to continue the roll-up some more - and repeat this sequence until it is completely closed. We just changed the window motor but it still acts the same way and it’s really slow. What can be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

The rest of the assembly is called the "Window Regulator" and it is the mechanism that allows the window to move up and down in the frame without binding.

First off I'd check for any obstructions in the track.  Next check the regulator parts for wear or damage.  Often these just wear out due to being cheaply made. Once the regulator is out of alignment, the window will bind, especially when going UP and you have exactly what you're describing.  Replace it.